# Strange statistic

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

Let $N$ be a random integer and let $p_N(n)$ be its discrete density.
The statistic
\begin{equation}S(N)\triangleq\sum_{n=2}^\infty p_N(n)\,n\,(n-1)\end{equation}
has some specific meaning?
It is clear that in general it is not the variance of $N$, but it is instead
\begin{equation}S(N)=\mathbb{E}[N^2]-\mathbb{E}[N]\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{E}[N]$ denotes the expected value of $N$. In fact
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}S(N)&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty p_N(n)\,n^2 -\sum_{n=2}^\infty p_N(n)\,n\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_N(n)\,n^2-p_N(1)\right)-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_N(n)\,n-p_N(1)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_N(n)\,n^2-\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_N(n)\,n\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N^2]-\mathbb{E}[N]\end{aligned}\end{equation}
The statistic $S(N)$ is the variance only if $N$ has expected value equal to zero.

Comment: $S(N)$ is the variance iff $\Bbb E[N]=\Bbb E[N]^2\iff\Bbb E[N]=0,1$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \text{The $k$th} \textbf{ factorial moment } \text{of the} \\
& \text{distribution of the random variable $X$} \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E\big( \,\underbrace{X(X-1)(X-2)\cdots(X-k+1)}_\text{$k$ factors} \, \big) 
\end{align}

The only reason that I know of (but I am ignorant of many things) why this is of interest is that it can be neatly computed in cases where $X$ has a Poisson distribution, and then the moments of the Poisson distribution may be computed by applying some algebra after that.

\begin{align}
& \text{Suppose } X \sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda). \text{ Then} \\[10pt]
& \operatorname E\big( X(X-1)(X-2)\cdots(X-k+1) \big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x\,=\,0}^\infty x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1) \Pr(X=x) \tag 1 \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x\,=\,k}^\infty x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1) \Pr(X=x) \\
& \text{because the sum of the first $k$ terms on line $(1)$ above is 0} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x\,=\,k}^\infty x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1)\cdot\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x\,=\,k}^\infty \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{(x-k)!} = \sum_{y\,=\,0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{y+k} e^{-\lambda}}{y!} \quad \text{where } y = x-k \\[8pt]
= {} & \lambda^k \sum_{y\,=\,0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!} \qquad = \lambda^k.
\end{align}

**Proposition:** The first $n$ moments of the distribution of the number of fixed points of a uniformly distributed random permutation of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are the same as the first $n$ moments of the Poisson distribution with expected value $1.$

**Proof:** The first $n$ factorial moments are the same; therefore the first $n$ moments are the same. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: Your interpretation of $S(N)$ as a factorial moment is right. Actually I'm studying the point process theory and I've found that the factorial moments can be converted in the "usual" moments (see Daley&Jones - An Introduction to the Theory of Point Processes (volume 1) - section 5.2)...

Comment: ...From what I've understood, the factorial moments are more handy to derive than the usual moments. Thus, firstly one compute the factorial moments and then compute the moments of interest. For example, in Advances in Statistical
Multisource-Multitarget Information Fusion, Mahler shows how to find the variance of a random variable in function of the first two factorial moments (equation 4.70).